# Is there any way to tell Flask to ignore a path?

Tags: python, apache, routes, flask

Currently my Flask is serving from root path like `http://example.com/` so it basically serves every request incoming to it. But I have the necessity to serve `http://example.com/start` from Apache and not trough Flask.

So I'd like to know if there is any way to tell Flask to ignore `@app.route("/start")` or to tell Flask to let apache override the path serving.

I'm using a shared host server so I don't have access to apache configuration files.

Thanks in advance, if there is any information needed feel free to ask.

Comment: You'll need to configure Apache to do this. By the time it gets to Flask, Apache has already seen it and handed it off, and Flask has no way of saying "No, this is something you need to handle".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the time Flask is handling a request, the web server has already passed the request to the application and is awaiting a response.  At that point, there's no protocol for Flask to "cancel" handling the request.  You'll need to modify Apache's configuration to only pass requests which do not match your path to the Flask application.  If you're on a shared host, you might still be able to modify an `.htaccess` file to set up the forwarding rules.

Comment: Actually, it would be nice to present examples of such forwarding rules.